# C# xml parsing error in webbrowser object

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, browser

I'm developing Windows app. with C#

i am connecting to websites (on webbrowser) and getting source code, it's not problem but when i was trying to connect a XML uri  and get source codes it's haveing problem.

The problem is "**The XML page cannot be displayed**"

i suspect that the source code has been written wrong
Because the code start with

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

How can i resolve this problem and get xml source codes ?

Comment: Can you post some more source code?

Comment: What kind of source code? I'm using for getting source webBrowser.DocumentText; property that's running witout problem. The problem in XML. i have to read that page source :(

Answer (score 0):

One option is that you are getting valid XML, but it refers to XSL that you have no access to.

`<?XML...>` should not cause this error since it should be not considered XML at all (should be `<?xml...` )